# Create new Array using two Arrays Specific data and values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a new Array using two arrays.

```
itemsAll = [
    {id: 1, itemId: 1, serialNo:"11111111", itemTypeId: 1, itemMasterId: 1, itemStatus: 0, updatedBy: 1 },
    {id: 2, itemId: 2, serialNo:"2222222", itemTypeId: 3, itemMasterId: 2, itemStatus: 0, updatedBy: 1 }
];
```

There is a itemTypeId i want to get itemTypeName match with itemTypeId.

```
itemType = [
    {id: 3, itemTypeId: 1, itemTypeName: "type Name 1", description: "Hello", itemTypeStatus: 0, status: true },
    {id: 13, itemTypeId: 2, itemTypeName: "type Name 2", description: "222 Hello", itemTypeStatus: 0, status: true },
    {id: 15 , itemTypeId: 3, itemTypeName: "type Name 3", description: "333 Hello", itemTypeStatus: 0, status: true }
];
```

**Expected Array**

```
itemsAllNew = [
    {id: 1, itemId: 1, serialNo:"11111111", itemTypeId: 1, itemTypeName: "type Name 1", itemMasterId: 1, itemStatus: 0, updatedBy: 1 },
    {id: 2, itemId: 2, serialNo:"2222222", itemTypeId: 3, , itemTypeName: "type Name 3", itemMasterId: 2, itemStatus: 0, updatedBy: 1 }
];
```

I added below tried solution but its contain unwanted key-value pairs also.

```
const output = itemsAll.map(
    itemsall => Object.assign(itemsall, itemType.find((itemtype) => itemtype.itemTypeId === itemsall.itemTypeId))
);

console.log(output);
```

Attached screenshot of output.

[image]

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: foreach and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: It is not clear what you really want. You didn’t give us the criteria for associating the two matrices and you also didn’t give us a try

Comment: @adiga I added code I tried.

Comment: @AksJacoves I added what I am tried, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object and map it with time complexity `O(1)`:

```
const mapItemType = new Map(itemType.map(i => [i.itemTypeId, i.itemTypeName]));
const result = itemsAll.map(({itemTypeId, ...other}) => 
   ({itemTypeName: mapItemType.get(itemTypeId), ...other }))
```

An example:

```js
let itemsAll = [
    {id: 1, itemId: 1, serialNo:"11111111", itemTypeId: 1, itemMasterId: 1, itemStatus: 0, updatedBy: 1 },
    {id: 2, itemId: 2, serialNo:"2222222", itemTypeId: 3, itemMasterId: 2, itemStatus: 0, updatedBy: 1 }
];

let itemType = [
    {id: 3, itemTypeId: 1, itemTypeName: "type Name 1", description: "Hello", itemTypeStatus: 0, status: true },
    {id: 13, itemTypeId: 2, itemTypeName: "type Name 2", description: "222 Hello", itemTypeStatus: 0, status: true },
    {id: 15 , itemTypeId: 3, itemTypeName: "type Name 3", description: "333 Hello", itemTypeStatus: 0, status: true }
];

const mapItemType = new Map(itemType.map(i => [i.itemTypeId, i.itemTypeName]));
const result = itemsAll.map(({itemTypeId, ...other}) => ({itemTypeName: mapItemType.get(itemTypeId), ...other }))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `itemsAll` array and check with the `itemTypeId` of the item in `itemType` array.

```js
const itemsAll = [
    {id: 1, itemId: 1, serialNo:"11111111", itemTypeId: 1, itemMasterId: 1, itemStatus: 0, updatedBy: 1 },
    {id: 2, itemId: 2, serialNo:"2222222", itemTypeId: 3, itemMasterId: 2, itemStatus: 0, updatedBy: 1 }
];

const itemType = [
    {id: 3, itemTypeId: 1, itemTypeName: "type Name 1", description: "Hello", itemTypeStatus: 0, status: true },
    {id: 13, itemTypeId: 2, itemTypeName: "type Name 2", description: "222 Hello", itemTypeStatus: 0, status: true },
    {id: 15 , itemTypeId: 3, itemTypeName: "type Name 3", description: "333 Hello", itemTypeStatus: 0, status: true }
];

const findItemTypes = (items, types) => {
  return items.map(item => {
    const { itemTypeName } = (types.find(type => type.itemTypeId === item.itemTypeId) || {});
    return {
    ...item,
    itemTypeName
    }
  })
}

console.log(findItemTypes(itemsAll, itemType))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: There is a unwanted data "description": "Hello" how to exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

So you mean you are getting extra key value pairs. e.g. description: '222 Hello' but you don't want that.. So if your solution is working fine then all you need to do is remove the unnecessary fields. One way would be using the map function.

```
const newArr = arr.map(({Title, ...rest}) => ({...rest}))
```

This would remove the Title field and give you the remaining fields. You can do similarly for your use case.

Comment: That could be simplified to `arr.map(({ Title, ...rest}) => rest)`